# Make {sideways} a synonym of {rotating}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

At the moment there are 42 questions tagged [rotating](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotating) and 18 questions tagged [sideways](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sideways). (6 questions feature both tags.) [rotating](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotating) is used for for the general concept of rotating (with the help, of. e.g., macros from the `graphicx` package) as well as for questions about the [`rotating`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating) package and its `sidewaysfigure` and `sidewaystable` environments. For the latter, sometimes the [sideways](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sideways) tag is used additionally or instead. I propose to make [sideways](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sideways) a synonym of [rotating](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotating) and to merge the existings tags/questions.

Note that there is also the [landscape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landscape) tag which is used for questions about changing paper orientation from portrait to landscape. Although there's some overlapping with [rotating](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotating), I think [landscape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landscape) is warranted as a separate tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I merged [rotating](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotating) and [sideways](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sideways) and kept the latter as a synonym for remapping. Otherwise it would be possible that the [sideways](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sideways) tag could reappear, because tag auto-suggestion doesn't work here since the tags are not similarly written.

Answer (score 4):

I created a tag wiki excerpt for [rotating](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotating):

> {rotating} is for general questions about rotating document elements
>   as well as for questions about the `rotating` package and its
>   `sidewaysfigure` and `sidewaystable` (floating) environments. For
>   general {rotating} questions add other tags specifying what should be
>   rotated.

I ask a moderator to make [sideways](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sideways) a synonym of [rotating](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotating) and to merge the existings tags/questions.